# cpanspec option --filter-requires fails to remove :MODULE_COMPAT

Tags: perl, rpm, cpan, rhel

I would like to make a rpm which can install on RHEL5,6 and 7.

```
[p4474668@rhel7dev source]$ cpanspec webmin-ajax-0.00.tar.gz  -d '' --force --filter-requires 'perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3)' -b
(... lots of infos here ...)
[p4474668@rhel7dev source]$ rpm -qpR noarch/perl-webmin-ajax-0.00-1.noarch.rpm
perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3)
perl(DST::System)
perl(WebminCore)
perl(lib)
perl(strict)
perl(warnings)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1useless
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Since the dependancy is not removed, it cannot be installed on a RHEL5.

How to remove the `perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3)` not required  dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is under-documented, and doesn't (IMHO) do all of what its name implies.

What it does is:

- along with the `.spec` file it creates a filter script file (some `sed` in a `.sh` script), this is referenced in the `.spec` file and is required during `rpmbuild`. The dependencies written to the `.spec` file are not affected by filtering.
- that `sed` filter script is rewritten by `sed` during `rpmbuild` to invoke the correct `perl.req`.
- the filter script is applied *only* to the output of `perl.req` (which is normally *only* invoked by `find-requires`)

(As far as I can tell, `perl.req` predates explicitly listed dependencies in `Makefile.PL` and/or the `META` files. What it does is look for likely `use` and `require` directives in perl code with some logic and regex's, the implementation of which is exactly as attractive as you'd expect).

To be honest I'm not *entirely* sure in what circumstances `perl.req` and `find-requires` are or are not invoked (cursory testing by setting `AutoReq` didn't have an effect for me), but `cpanspec` reads and processes `META.yml` directly if found in any case. The only other dependency-related functionality is (rudimentary) processing of `Makefile.PL` to extract modules references in `PREREQ_PM` and add those as `BuildRequires`

Normally you can patch up your `.spec` file to [add something like](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL:Packaging_Autoprovides_and_Requires_Filtering)

```
%filter_from_requires /XSLoader/d
%filter_setup
```

However, `:MODULE_COMPAT_xxx` is a *special-case dependency* in `cpanspec`, you can turn it off with the `-o` option to create "compatible" RPMs that work on older systems. This has other effects too, so it might be less problematic to build in discrete steps so that you can tweak the build:

```
cpanspec [...]   yourmodule
sed -i'.bak' '/^Requires.*:MODULE_COMPAT.*/d' yourmodule.spec
rpmbuild -ba yourmodule.spec
```

(especially since `cpanspec` warns that `-b` is not guaranteed to work always).

Of course the final package may not work as expected, `cpanspec` is being cautious, but there might be a real API requirement for this constraint (in your case the "noarch" build may limit the scope for problems, I think). The *rule of thumb* is that API/ABI's try to be backward compatible, not forward compatible (a related problem occurs if you try to build binaries to work with a glibc *older* than the one you compile against).

You may have better luck building on a CentOS 5 system (or investigate [Mock](https://github.com/perfsonar/project/wiki/CentOS-Mock-Overview) for a more complete solution).